# /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv does not exist. [Ubuntu Server 20.04]

Tags: ubuntu, boot, filesystems, ubuntu-server, ubuntu-20.04

Today I deleted LAMP stack from my Ubuntu 20.04 server using tasksel and, when I rebooted the server, instead of booting as usual it gave me that error:

```
Gave up waiting for root file system device. Common problems:
- Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)
 — check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?)
- Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; le /dev)
ALERT! /dev/mapper/ubuntu—-vg—ubuntu—-le does not exist. Dropping to shell!
```

Before showing it, he repeated for a lot of times the following logs:

```
blk_update_request: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0 op 0x0: (READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0’
floppy: error 10 while reading block 0
mdadm: No arrays found in config file or automatically
```

I’m new to Linux but I thought that it could be a problem with file system... so I tried fixing it with `fsck` (I found online that it could repair Ubuntu’s file system) using:

```
touch /forcefsck
```

and then rebooting but it didn’t work :(

Can someone help me? How can I fix the problem and come back to my GNOME interface?